# First time I've seen this syntax in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to learn the Node.js Stripe API. And I was wondering what exactly is this syntax ?

```
var stripe = require("stripe") ("some_test_key");
```

Why the require function has two parenthesis ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require()` returns a function which is then called. You could also write it like this:

```
var func = require("stripe");
var stripe = func("some_test_key");
```